Triplet of spinons of a gapped $Z_2$ spin liquid from Sachdev's textbook
My question concerns Sachdev's Quantum Phases of Matters, sec 15.4.1.
To quickly recap, we started with a nearest neighbor antiferromagnetic spin model on 2D triangular lattice.  The spin was fractionalized into Schwinger bosons $s_{i\mu}$. Here $i$ is lattice site and $\mu = \uparrow, \downarrow$ is spin-1/2 index. And we are basically doing meanfield theory around some given VBS order
$$
Q_{ij} = \langle \epsilon^{\mu\nu} s^{\dagger}_{i\mu} s^{\dagger}_{j\nu} \rangle = \text{const},
$$
where $i, j$ are nearest neighbor.
Anyway, in the opening paragraph of 15.4.1, Sachdev splits the triangular lattice into three sublattices by claiming that the spinon operator $s$ naturally becomes a triplet $(u, v, w)$ in each unit cell.  See diagram below.

This seems pure nonsense to me.  $u, v, w$ are all equivalent on a triangular lattice.  And it was said that the particular meanfield ansatz breaks no symmetry whatsoever, so we shouldn't have an enlarged unit cell either.  He cited his own paper for this treatment (Phys. Rev. B 84 (2011) 094419), but that one is on a Kagome lattice, where you do have three types of sites.
Am I missing something big, or was Sachdev not thinking clearly when writing the chapter?
